# Cant connect to scassandra (stubbed cassandra) using datastax-driver

Tags: node.js, macos, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have troubles connecting to cassandra.
Im trying to connect to s-cassandra (which is a stubbed cassandra as can be reviewed [here](http://scassandra-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/standalone/overview/)), with a **datastax node.js cassandra driver**.

For some reason passing "127.0.0.1:8042" as a contact point to the driver 
 results in a **DriverInternalError**:

( tough  sometimes it does work randomly and I havent still figured out why  sometimes it does and sometime i doesnt..)

The **DriverInternalError** I get:

> {"name": "DriverInternalError",
>   "stack": "...", 
>   
>   "message": "Local datacenter could not be
>   determined", 
>    "info": "Represents a bug inside the driver or in a
>   Cassandra host." }

That is what I see from Cassandra Driver's log:

```
log event: info -- Adding host 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: info -- Getting first connection
log event: info -- Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Socket connected to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: info -- Trying to use protocol version 4
log event: verbose -- Sending stream #0
log event: verbose -- Sent stream #0 to 127.0.0.1:8042
{"name":"application-storage","hostname":"Yuris-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":1338,"level":30,"msg":"Kafka producer is initialized","time":"2016-08-05T12:53:53.124Z","v":0}
log event: verbose -- Received frame #0 from 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: info -- Protocol v4 not supported, using v2
log event: verbose -- Done receiving frame #0
log event: verbose -- disconnecting
log event: info -- Connection to 127.0.0.1:8042 closed
log event: info -- Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Socket connected to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: info -- Trying to use protocol version 2
log event: verbose -- Sending stream #0
log event: verbose -- Sent stream #0 to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Received frame #0 from 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: info -- Connection to 127.0.0.1:8042 opened successfully
log event: info -- Connection pool to host 127.0.0.1:8042 created with 1 connection(s)
log event: info -- Control connection using protocol version 2
log event: info -- Connection acquired to 127.0.0.1:8042, refreshing nodes list
log event: info -- Refreshing local and peers info
log event: verbose -- Sending stream #1
log event: verbose -- Done receiving frame #0
log event: verbose -- Sent stream #1 to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Received frame #1 from 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: warning -- No local info provided
log event: verbose -- Sending stream #0
log event: verbose -- Done receiving frame #1
log event: verbose -- Sent stream #0 to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Received frame #0 from 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: info -- Peers info retrieved
log event: error -- Tokenizer could not be determined
log event: info -- Retrieving keyspaces metadata
log event: verbose -- Sending stream #1
log event: verbose -- Done receiving frame #0
log event: verbose -- Sent stream #1 to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Received frame #1 from 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Sending stream #0
log event: verbose -- Done receiving frame #1
log event: verbose -- Sent stream #0 to 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: verbose -- Received frame #0 from 127.0.0.1:8042
log event: info -- ControlConnection connected to 127.0.0.1:8042 and is up to date
```

Ive tried playing with the firewall and open application but help is not there.. tough  sometimes it does work randomly and I havent still figured out why..
I have a mac OS X El Capitan

Comment: It looks like it is not related to network, it's related to how the node is configured: The driver fetches the information of the datacenter from `system.local` table, make sure the data is filled in scassandra.

Comment: should I stub this table in scassandra?

Answer (score 1):

The Solution that helped me:
I needed to prime the system.local  table as a prime-query-single

```
{
        query: 'prime-query-single',
        header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: {
            "when": {
                "query": "SELECT * FROM system.local WHERE key='local'"
            },
            "then": {
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "cluster_name": "custom cluster name",
                        "partitioner": "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner",
                        "data_center": "dc1",
                        "rack": "rc1",
                        "tokens": [
                            "1743244960790844724"
                        ],
                        "release_version": "2.0.1"
                    }
                ],
                "result": "success",
                "column_types": {
                    "tokens": "set<text>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```